# prevent BufferedReader from closing the file for a list of files

Tags: python, bufferedreader

I have a class which extends BufferedReader, and a list of file streams
b.close() is called for all except the last stream, I want to keep the streams open
How do I do this?

thanks

```
class TestReader(BufferedReader):
    pass

def test(streams):
    for stream in streams:
        b=TestReader(stream)
        do_something(b)
    #all the streams except streams[-1] are closed, how do I prevent this?

streams=[open('test1.txt','rb'),open('test2.txt','rb')]
test(streams)
streams.do_something_else()
```

Comment: Actually, at the point where your comment appears, the streams are still open.

Comment: no they are not, try doing streams[0].read()

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I had a bug in my test script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though in the implementation `BufferedIOBase` classes wrap an `IOBase` object, their interface is a stream (*everything* inherits from `IOBase`), so the ordinary behavior of a `IOBase` object is to close themselves when they go out of scope. `BufferedIOBase` just delegates the `close()` call to the underlying stream.

**You shouldn't view a `BufferedReader` as a stream wrapper (although that is how it is implemented), but as a type-casting of an existing stream.**  The state of the two streams is completely bound together. However, you can unbind the wrapped stream with `detach()`, but this leaves the `BufferedIOBase` object useless.

Additionally, `io.open` returns a `BufferedReader` already when mode is `rb`, so you are double-buffering. You should use `io.FileIO` instead.

You have a few choices:

1. Create a new stream and a new underlying file descriptor, and pass around file names instead of streams. This is your easiest and safest option.
2. Create raw file descriptors and create streams from them as needed. This requires some
   care that multiple streams are not using the same file descriptor at the same time. For example:

   ```
   fd = os.open('test.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
   file1 = FileIO(fd, 'r', closefd=False)
   file2 = FileIO(fd, 'r', closefd=False)

   file1.read(100)
   assert file1.tell() == 100
   file2.read(100)
   assert file1.tell() == 200
   ```
3. `detach()` the underlying stream before your `BufferedIOBase` object closes its stream. (Remember to rewind the stream!)

   ```
   def test(streams):
       for stream in streams:
           b=TestReader(stream)
           do_something(b)
           wrappedstream = b.detach()
           assert wrappedstream is stream
   ```

   You can even implement this in your destructor:

   ```
   class TestReader(BufferedReader):
       def __del__(self):
           self.detach()
           # self.raw will not be closed,
           # rather left in the state it was in at detachment
   ```

   Or just disable `close()` delegation completely if you think the semantics are wrong:

   ```
   class TestReader(BufferedReader):
       def close(self):
           self.closed = True
   ```

I don't have the big picture of what you are doing (possibly you need a different design), but this is how I would implement the code I see:

```
from io import FileIO, BufferedReader
import io
import os

class TestReader(BufferedReader):
    pass

def test(streams):
    for stream in streams:
        b = TestReader(stream)

def test_reset(streams):
    """Will try to leave stream state unchanged"""
    for stream in streams:
        pos = stream.tell()
        b = TestReader(stream)
        do_something(b)
        b.detach()
        stream.seek(pos)



filenames = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt']

# option 1: just make new streams

streams = [FileIO(name, 'r') for name in filenames]
test(streams)
streams = [io.open(name, 'rb') for name in filenames]
#etc


# option 2: use file descriptors
fds = [os.open(name, os.O_RDONLY) for name in filenames]
#closefd = False means "do not close fd on __del__ or __exit__"
#this is only an option when you pass a fd instead of a file name
streams = [FileIO(fd, 'r', closefd=False) for fd in fds]
test(streams)
streams = []
for fd in fds:
    os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
    streams.append(io.open(fd, 'rb', closefd=False))
    # you can also .seek(0) on the BufferedReader objects
    # instead of os.lseek on the fds


# option 3: detach

streams = [FileIO(name, 'r') for name in filenames]
test_reset(streams)
# streams[*] should still be in the same state as when you passed it in
```

Comment: I do want to do something with them, after test(), is there no way around this? I understand the streams are not referenced so are deleted, but making a new list increases memory usage (I have a lot of streams)

Comment: This is not the issue. The `BufferedReader` seems to be closing the streams when the reference to it is lost; keeping the streams around in a list does not prevent them from getting closed.

Comment: It does but to do this I would need to add a useless parameter to test() so the list is not deferenced

Comment: I've temporarily added a method to TestReader so that close() will not be called immediately, but this is just a work-around

Comment: I've expanded the answer since you didn't seem to understand my first attempt. Basically `BufferedIOBase` (thus `BufferedReader`) is itself a stream (everything inherits from `IOBase`) so it closes itself when it goes out of scope (i.e. delegates `close()` to the wrapped stream). You shouldn't view a `BufferedReader` as a wrapper (although that is how it is implemented), but as a type-casting of an existing stream.